# Having a code that runs just in debug mode in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, preprocessor-directive

I have a piece of code in my Matlab implementation that is like a good comment but in a real scenario, the generated matrix is too big and I can't keep the code. So it is a comment now.

I want to know if there is something like debug mode in Matlab. Something like

```
#ifndef NDEBUG
```

in C?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like there's an undocumented method described [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/11530-detect-debug-mode).

```
if feature('IsDebugMode')
    % debug code
end
```

This appears to work in MATLAB 2017a.

Comment: Please provide details. What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? What version of MATLAB are you using? Could you provide minimal examples that don't work?

Comment: My Matlab is 8.6
I can put the if statement in my code, but it doesn't run even in debug mode. In the command line, I can get 
feature('IsDebugMode')==1
but it doesn't run

Comment: Ah I see. It looks like `feature('IsDebugMode')` only evaluates to true if you execute a script from within debug mode. For example, if you run any script with a breakpoint in it, then when the breakpoint is reached you execute another script from command window, then `feature('IsDebugMode')` will evaluate to true in the second script. Quite inconvenient!